# TableView not using the correct TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a grouped tableview and the datasource looks as follows:

```
let customCell = UITableViewCell()
customCell.textLabel?.text = "this is a custom cell"

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellA", for: indexPath) as! CellA

    cell.label.text = "dummy text"

    switch indexPath.section {
    case 0 :
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0 : cell.label.text = "Foo"
        case 1 : cell.label.text = "Bar"
        default:
            fatalError("Row does not exist")
        }
    case 1 :
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0 : return customCell
        default:
            fatalError("Row does not exist")
        }
    default:
        fatalError("Section does not exist")
    }

    return cell
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 2 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0 : return 2
    case 1 : return 1
    default:
        fatalError("Section does not exist")
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
I want section 2 to use `customCell` but instead it's still using the cell I've created using the method `dequeueReusableCell(identifier:,indexPath:)`, having the dummy text `"dummy text"`. This doesn't happen if I use the method: `dequeueReusableCell(identifier:)` (without `indexPath`).

What is the proper way of doing this or should I just use the method without `indexPath`?

Comment: Have you debugged to check whether or not the line `case 0: return customCell` is ever reached?

Comment: You should set up the cells text label data in `case 0` and `case 1`

Comment: @BenjaminLowry: yes, I've checked and it does reach `case 0:`. @zsteed: Even if I do that, the dequeued cell will get on top of `customCell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are doing almost correct, your `customCell` is also getting added to your `tableView`. But what is happening here is, at first you are `dequeueing` a cell in `cellForRowAt` and then checking for `section` and returning the `cell`. So Your `customCell` for `indexPath.section = 1` is added but the `dequeued` cell present on top of it. You can debug the `view hierarchy` and see the magic.

Now you have to move your `cell` creation to individual `section` and return from there, like below, it should work:

```
switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableVIew.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cellA
            cell.textLabel?.text = "dummy text"

            switch indexPath.row {
                case 0 :
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "Foo"
                    return cell
                case 1 :
                    cell.textLabel?.text = "Bar"
                    return cell
            default:
                fatalError("Row does not exist")
            }
        case 1:
            switch indexPath.row {
                case 0 :
                    return customCell
            default:
                fatalError("Row does not exist")
            }
        default:
             fatalError("Section does not exist")
     }
```

Comment: I haven't checked the view hierarchy before and you're right. The dequeued cell is on top of the `customCell`. I was actually hoping there was some way to do it as I've shown. The example I've used here just has 2 sections but in my original project I have a lot more and is just like your answer. Do you also happen to know why this doesn't happen when I use the dequeue method **without** the indexPath?

Comment: As per the docs in API reference(XCode docs), `Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated cell, in lieu of allocating a new one.` this is for without `indexPath` AND `newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered` with `indexPath`. So you must have learned now that for each `indexPath` it looks for a new cell to be dequeued/created.